What is the time source at boot for Ubuntu 24.04 with no RTC?
I am running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on a Raspberry pi with Linux 6.8.0-1017-raspi.
When the system boots it appears to be using the timestamp of something on disk to use as the system time.
In /var/log/syslog you can see the time getting set to 2024-08-08T14:52:24
2024-12-23T16:42:48.757776+00:00 webserver systemd[1]: Stopping rsync.service - fast remote file copy program daemon...
2024-08-08T14:52:24.651037+00:00 webserver systemd-modules-load[365]: Inserted module 'dm_multipath'

I have read elsewhere that it gets the time from the mtime of /var/lib/systemd/timesync/clock or /var/lib/private/systemd/timesync/clock but that isn't happening.
The system does have an RTC on the I2C but, for reasons, that doesn't get enabled until much later in the boot sequence. Once the RTC fires up then the time gets set correctly.
Before I added the RTC the time was getting set correctly by chrony, but again this is also late on in the boot process. It would be nice if syslog had something approximating the correct time for the initial part of the boot sequence. If I knew the file which is used as the reference then a simple cron job to touch that file once a minute would suffice for my needs.
There are numerous files on the system with an mtime of 2024-12-23T16:42:48 and I could try touching each one in turn then rebooting, and I may eventually discover that one of these files is being used as the start time. But there must be someone here who knows.

Raspberry Pi comes with a RTC chip which is powered as long as the Pi is plugged in. See Raspberry Pi forum thread.
